# Image View array in ViewPager Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to show multiple images in view pager from URL, below is my code i am not sure on how to add a imageview array to my code. Please help

```
 ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.padding_medium);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);

    String[] imageGalleryStr = {
            "http://blogs.nature.com/news/files/elections%20small.JPG",
            "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/Small_icosihemidodecahedron.png/100px-Small_icosihemidodecahedron.png",
            "http://blogs.nature.com/news/files/elections%20small.JPG",
            "http://blogs.nature.com/news/files/elections%20small.JPG"};

    for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)//file.length;i++) {

        new LoadImage(imageView).execute(imageGalleryStr[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView,i);

    }
```

Comment: You don't know how to make a List or array of objects?

Comment: Dude just dig on google !

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a List ImageView  .
Then use PagerAdapter.

Also how to use <> ? it's empty when i put something inside.

Comment: This answer is pretty vague as is. Maybe you could add more detail, i.e. some working code?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're parsing images online you might want to add these URLs to a JSONArray and parse them using a library such as Volley in Volley there is a class called `NetworkImageView` you can use it to parse your data.

Take a look at Android Hive's [article](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) on parsing images and text.